# Fetch Data from WatermelonDB in React

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, react-native, watermelondb

I am using WatermelonDB as a local database of my app.
I have a method `getPlaces()` inside a class AccessDB:

```
static async getPlaces() {
        const postsCollection = database.collections.get('places');
        const allPosts = await postsCollection.query().fetch();
        return allPosts;
}
```

Calling `getPlaces()` using `AccessDB.getPlaces()` with async and await works. How can I fetch the results matching the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `allPosts` is an array with all `places` in your case. So to access the properties of the places, you would do in a different class:

```
import AccessDB from './AccessDB';
```

and then somewhere for example

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const places = await AccessDB.getPlaces();

        var buffer = '';
        for (place in places) {
            buffer += places[place].name + '\n'
        }
        console.log(buffer)
    } catch(e) {console.log(e)}
})()
```

You have to be carefully when debugging with console.log, as

1) console.log skips outputs if executed fast one after the other, e.g. if you console.log the `places[place].name` every time in the for-loop above and

2) **if you `console.log(places)` you see the same as if you `console.log(database)` which is very confusing. You would expect to see [Object object],[Object object]..., which you see when you use `alert(places)`.**

Comment: Your second point really had me going crazy, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding fully. But did you try to put query inside your `query` method

```
const allPosts = await postsCollection.query(Q.where('is_verified', true)).fetch();
```

Also do not forget that `getPlaces` is async and your need **`async\await`** to get return data.

Comment: When I printed `allPosts`, I realized, that `allPosts` equals my database object.
I.e `database.collections.get('places') = database`
Why isn't it extracting those places?